# Recover from sudo rm -R /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7

Tags: python, xcode, macos, homebrew, symlink

I was following this [tutorial](https://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/installing_python_osx/) for removing older versions/symlinks of Python, so I could use python 3.5, and have it be my default version

The command:

> sudo rm -R /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7

appears to have broken my entire development environment. I started experiencing errors with `homebrew`, `git`, `Xcode`, `sublime text 2`, etc. I partially fixed it by re-downloading `python 2.7` and running `brew doctor && brew prune`

However, I still cannot get sublime text 2 to open. I believe I need to restore my `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/` directory to have 2.7, but I do not know how to do this

I also ran `brew install python` as a potential solution but this did not work.

I am by no means an expert in the terminal, but I'm trying to get better. I am often following tutorials like the one I reference to install new software. my questions are as follows:

1. How can I recover from this?
2. What are some good tips for avoiding future issues like this?
3. Where can I learn more about important things to know in the terminal, so I can become a terminal boss.
4. Should I just start using home-brew for all developer-related installations?

Comment: Are there any symlinks in `/usr/local/bin` that link to the non-existing Python? If so, remove them and run `brew prune`, and then `brew doctor` and do what it tells you.

Comment: Do you have a _Time Machine_ backup you can recover from?

Comment: @L3viathan As far as I can tell everything points to the Cellar versions or the versions in /Library/... I think I have fixed everything but sublime text which I believe is looking for something in /System/Library/... which has version 3.5 and Current which points to 3.5

Comment: @AustinHastings It seems I don't have a backup as when I opened TimeMachine it told me I haven't selected a location for backup. I'm learning more already! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You deleted a component of the operating system. Don't do that -- leave `/System` alone. (Mac OS X 10.10 and later enforce this by preventing you from modifying that directory at all by default, even with root access.)

There is no supported way to restore this. Back up your data and reinstall the OS.

Comment: Thanks, this is good advice for questions 1 and 2. Can you refer  to any good online materials for unix/osx? Also, what about homebrew? Should I just always be using that?

Comment: Sometimes system python is the best tool, as it is apple's version of python. Just be careful when interacting with the `/System` folder.

Comment: I managed to reinstall it from https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/ I'm one of these people: https://xkcd.com/1987/